# I am trying to add more content to an existing excel file, can anyone tell me is there any method can be used from gembox.speadsheet?

Tags: append, gembox-spreadsheet

I already have the path of the Excel file, but whenever I call save method, the program writes new content to UTC.xlsx file.

**string pathString = "C:\Users\ADMIN-PC\Documents\SUMMER 2018\PRN192\CreateFile\SubFolder\UTC.xlsx";
ef.Save(pathString);**

Comment: the `ef.save(pathString)` will override old data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gembox Spreadsheet add column without remove the other ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430096/gembox-spreadsheet-add-column-without-remove-the-other-ones)

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me the specific method?#giaosudauto

Comment: You need to load the existing Excel file and then write your new content into it and then save. So something like: var ef = ExcelFile.Load(pathString); /* Write new content ... */ ef. Save(pathString);

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var path = @"C:\Users\ADMIN-PC\Documents\SUMMER 2018\PRN192\CreateFile\SubFolder\UTC.xlsx";

// Load the workbook:
var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(path);

// Manipulate the workbook … 
// … and save it over the original
workbook.Save(path);
```